# Solaris + display file time stamp [year][month][day]

Tags: solaris, ls, date, timestamps

I have Solaris 10 machine

I need to verify time stamp of some file in my Solaris machine

And to get the following format

```
 [year][month][day]
```

Example of working command on Linux

```
  ls -l --time-style=+%Y%m%d /etc/hosts | awk '{print $6}'
  20121107   <----- ( expected results )
```

- remark I can't to install gnu ls on My solaris machine!

On my solaris machine I try the following commands but all them not works ( because Solaris flags are different from Linux ) , and stat command not defined in my Solaris

```
# ls -l -T -D %Y%m%d /etc/hosts
ls: illegal option -- T
ls: illegal option -- D
usage: ls -1RaAdCxmnlhogrtuvVcpFbqisfHLeE@ [files]
```

```
# stat /etc/hosts | awk '/Access/{print $2}' | tail -n1 | tr -d'' '-'
ksh: stat:  not found
```

Please advice if there are some other ways to get stamp date of file ( not by ls or stat command ) , maybe with date command ? in order to give me the solution,

As the following:

```
   <solaris>   command /etc/hosts 

               [year][month][day]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Solaris (>= 10) the ls command has  the -E option. So your command could be as simple as 
    `ls -E /etc/hosts`  or 
`ls -E /etc/hosts | awk '{print $6}'| sed 's#-##g'`

to get the desired result.

Comment: great solution thx allot

Answer (score 3):

A portable way to do it could be:

```
perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime((lstat)[9]) for @ARGV' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: great solution!